# How to call overloaded function based on constness and return type?

Tags: c++, constants, overriding

A rookie question here. I have noticed something similar with what I am trying to achieve in the cryptic vector class:

```
iterator begin();
const_iterator begin() const;
```

I have tried to achieve this with the following implementation:

```
#include <iostream>

class User
{
public:
  class A
  {
  public:
    A(){ std::cout << "A constructor" << std::endl; }
  };

  class B
  {
  public:
    B(){ std::cout << "B constructor" << std::endl;}
  };
public:
  A begin() { return A(); }
  B begin() const { return B(); }
};

int main()
{
  User u;

  User::A a = u.begin();
  User::B b = u.begin();
}
```

With this code, I can call the A constructor yet cannot find a way how to call the B constructor.

I get the following error message:

```
no user-defined conversion from User::A to User::B
```

Which, I guess, is indicative that the wrong member function is called.

Any tips? :)

Comment: What about doing `const_cast<const User&>(u).begin()` or `std::as_const(u).begin()`?

Comment: @Evg sweet, this works! Still curious though, how come with vector iterators one does not need to explicitly cast begin function to const? And this works: ```std::vector<int>::const_iterator = v.begin();```

Comment: If it works, then `vector::iterator` is convertible to `vector::const_iterator`. You may want to define proper conversion constructor/operator.

Comment: @VytautasK Iterators in the standard library are implemented such that they can be implicitly converted into constant iterators, like `T*` can be implicitly converted into `const T*` (but not vice versa).

Answer (score 4):

Before solving the problem, I'll add a small comment so that you understand why C++ behaves that way.

Basically, `const` functions are there so that you could expose different APIs when you are accessing mutable vs immutable object instances.

So, for example, you might have define an API that returns a list of `const User`-s that only allow calling specific getter methods, whereas a different API would return a single (non-const) `User` for editing.

The compiler automatically uses the right method according to the const-ness of the instance you are using.

So, if you have a `const User a` and `User b`, for user `a`, the default is going to be the `const` prototype, and for user `b`, the default is going to be the non-`const` one, and it falls back to the `const` one if none exists.

Note: As Goswin correctly pointed out, is that the compiler has no way of choosing a method by its return type, but rather only by examining its arguments. C++ methods, as in, functions attached to class instances, pass an "implicit" pointer to the class instance, called `this`. When defining a `const` method, you're basically telling the compiler to pass a `const` pointer as opposed to a regular one for non-`const` ones.

Just like others pointed out:

1. If you cast your user into a `const` one, you can call the `const` prototype.
2. OR, if you define or return a `const User` variable, you'll also access the const prototype as well.

There are different ways to cast:

- C way `(const User&)u` (which you should avoid, but be able to recognize)
- Classic `const_cast<const User&>(u)`
- C++17 `std::as_const(u)`

And you can always return a `const` reference to an object from a method if you wanna expose only the `const` prototypes.

Comment: You should also mention that functions are not chosen depending on their return type, only their argument, and for classes there is an implicit `this` argument.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, good suggestion! Will do

Comment: I would call it `const *this` for the time being. Because `this` is always `const`.

Answer (score 2):

You need `const User`, [std::as_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) (C++17) might help:

```
User::B b = std::as_const(u).begin();
```

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is that the second overloaded `begin` is a `const` member function which means that when you write `u.begin()` the first non-const version will be preferred over the second const version since `u` is a nonconst `User` object.

To **solve** this one option is to use `const_cast` as shown below:

```
User::B b = const_cast<const User&>(u).begin();
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/pk32hni6e)